# Pygame Mixing Repeated Key Presses and Singular Key Presses

Tags: python, key, pygame, keypress

In Pygame, you can set repeated (held down) Key detection with pygame.key.set_repeat().

In my case, I want to mix keys that can be held down and keys that will only be recognized once. Specifically, I want to be able to Move (by holding down key(s)), but I want to require one key press per Fire Missile.

To be clearer, I want to recognize held-down key presses for movement keys (Up, Down, Left, Right, etc.) only. Other keys, when held down, should only be recognized once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep a state tracker for the keys you only want to recognize once per press - set a flag to `True` when you see a KEYDOWN event, and then set it to `False` again when you see a matching `KEYUP`. Then only respond to a `KEYDOWN` event if the flag wasn't already `True`.

The other option is that you can keep a state tracker for the keys you *do* want to repeat and just poll that state every so often (e.g. every X milliseconds, see if the key is marked as 'down' and if so, do whatever should be done for that keypress).

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense. I guess I was thinking that this problem would have been pretty common, so there might have already been a provided solution. But it's no problem to track it manually. Thanks again